# What rarity does each of the loot color represent?

Tags: borderlands

I know that the color of the loot signifies the rarity of that piece of loot but I don't know is the order. What is the order from rarest to common?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, Borderlands follow the standard color-coding system for RPGs. Here.

- Level 1 = White, rarity = 0-4.
- Level 2 = Green, rarity = 5-10.
- Level 3 = Blue, rarity = 11-15.
- Level 4 = Purple, rarity = 16-49.
- Level 5 = Light Orange, rarity = 50-60.
- Level 6 = Orange, rarity = 61-65.
- Level 7 = Dark Orange, rarity = 66-100.
- Level 8 = Pearlescent, rarity = 101+.

[Source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Rank), and another [one](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons#Rarity).

Comment: Hey i posted this question already but since you seem to know the game i have another question. This one is quite a bit more technical though so if you can't help its cool.

Comment: Let me start  by citing the specific situation that prompted this question. Early in the 1st Borderlands (limited carrying capacity) I had to choose between 2 sniper rifles the first had 198 damage, but 4x Explosive Element Effect; the second had 247 damage AND triple the fire rate. I've looked online but can't find any tables or explinations of the damage value of any of the elemental effects (including increased chances i.e. 1x 2x etc.)

Comment: If you have trouble remembering : **W**hen **G**randma **B**urps **P**atrick **O**beys (**W**hite **G**reen **B**lue **P**urple **O**range) and after that, Seraph Then Pearlescent